# Reading data from BaseDataBoundControl.DataSource (ASP.NET GridView)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datasource

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 GridView on a WebForm. 
The GridView gets data from an ObjectDataSource which is set via the DataSourceID property in the code in front. 
The ObjectDataSource returns a List of custom data class objects (just a class with public properties) to populate the GridView.

What I want to do is use the a List comsumed by the GridView in another code-behind method. At a high level:
1. GridView is loaded with List data from ObjectDataSource.
2. In the GridView.OnDataBound method I call GridView.DataSource to get the List object.
3. I enumerate the List and use the same data to do some other operation.

The theory being one less duplicated method call and one less call to the back-end database.

I've tried calling DataSource from the GridView' DataBound method and calling GridView.Rows[x].DataItem. In each case I only get a Null reference exception ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object").

Is there any way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the [`OnRowDataBound` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound.aspx). This way, you can use data from the row that was just databound:

```
protected void gvGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    CustomDataClass data = e.Row.DataItem as CustomDataClass;
    if (data != null) 
    {
        // access data here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But do you want the onRowDataBound event? It looks like you want the onDataBound event for the GridView's entire datasource...

So you don't necessarily want one instance (row) of CustomDataClass, you want the entire CustomDataClass[] array of rows to use somewhere else.

HELP! I need this too.

******UPDATE******

I found the answer. Do this as below and set the OnSelected event in your objectdatasource:

protected void ObjectDataSource_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            ObjectListRow[] objectArray = (ObjectListRow[])e.ReturnValue;
            List objectList = objectArray.ToList();
         }

It turns out my datasource was an array, but if yours is a List<> then just cast the e.ReturnValue as the List.

EASY CHEESY.